# joint_state ROS topic from Gazebo and ros_control

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am trying to learn Gazebo/ROS from the tutorials and I am confused about a couple of things.

1. When I run Gazebo as a ROS node, does Gazebo publish to the /joint_state topic? It does not seem like it does from looking at the topic subscriber/publisher graph. Is there a way for me to do this? It seems like necessary information to have for programming the robot from ROS. Also, I would like to view the state of the robot in rviz, which needs /tf data which in turn needs /joint_states (afaik).
2. I do not understand ros_control and how it works with gazebo at all. ros_control is pretty much undocumented in ROS. Any suggestions on where to start looking for information? Or if somebody could give me a quick high level overview that would be incredibly helpful.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4205/joint_state-ros-topic-from-gazebo-and-ros_control/) by [munnveed](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/457/munnveed/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 45 on 2013-08-20

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

**Question 1**

When using ros_control, the `/joint_states` topic is published by an instance of the `JointStateController`. This is a read-only controller that does not command any joint, but rather publishes the current joint states at a configurable frequency.

To run this controller you need to load its configuration to the ROS parameter server and load/start it in the controller manager. [This](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/blob/hydro-devel/joint_state_controller/joint_state_controller.launch) launch file in the controller's repository does just that.

Once you have a valid `joint_states` topic, `tf` should start publishing frame data, and tf-dependent Rviz plugins like RobotModel should also work.

**Question 2**

These resources are currently available:

- [Tutorial on ros_control with Gazebo](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/ROS_Control_with_Gazebo)
- [ros_control overview on the ROS wiki](http://ros.org/wiki/ros_control)
- [ros_control repository wiki](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control/wiki)

At some point these should probably be consolidated in a single place.

If you still have unanswered questions, don't hesitate to ask. There's a [ROS Control SIG](http://www.ros.org/wiki/sig/RobotControl) you might be interested in joining for ros_control-specific discussions.

Finally, consider that ros_control is not yet officially released, and not all parts of the documentation have reached maturity. Feature requests and patches are always welcome.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodríguez T](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26/adolfo-rodr%C3%ADguez-t/) with karma: 275 on 2013-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [munnveed](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/457/munnveed/) on 2013-08-21**:
Question 1: That explains it! Ok, I got my /joint_states published. It turns out there was a bug in the ROS control with Gazebo tutorial. The configuration of the joint_state_controller is setup in the parameter server but the controller was not loaded into the manager. I updated the wiki to fix that.

**Comment by [munnveed](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/457/munnveed/) on 2013-08-21**:
Question 2: Given that ros_control is not quite released, is there an alternative standard way in which control joints in Gazebo from ROS? How was it done before ros_control? Do I have to write my own plugin to interface with ROS? I very much appreciate your help. This is clarifying a lot of things for me.

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodríguez T](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26/adolfo-rodr%C3%ADguez-t/) on 2013-08-22**:
Before ros_control it was mostly a do-it-yourself thing. To save time, many people ended up adapting the pr2_controller_manager to their simulated robot, but that often resulted in different interfaces for the simulated and real robot scenarios. The ros_control project is in fact an evolution of the pr2_controller_manager aimed at being robot-agnostic.

Leveraging ros_control should be much less work than you doing a rewrite from scratch of a Gazebo plugin.

**Comment by [munnveed](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/457/munnveed/) on 2013-08-22**:
Thanks. I think I have gotten to the point where I can at least proceed further. I'm getting /joint_state updates and I can publish to the controllers to move my (toy) robot.

**Comment by [duhyu1](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4878/duhyu1/) on 2018-04-04**:
I remap /joint_states to /MY_ROBOT_NAME/joint_states when node robot_state_publisher is started. Even if joint_state_publisher is not started, why there will be a joint_states topic?

**Comment by [Kloping](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5261/kloping/) on 2018-05-18**:
Hi Munnveed, how did you manage to solve the question 1?  Do you need to write your own .yaml file to map all the joints?